# Android ObjectInputStream(openFileInput) always throws IOException

Tags: android, objectinputstream

I'm trying to read from internal storage (a file) however i'm having issues.

I get a `FileInputStream` for a file using `FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(filename)`.
The call is successful, nothing fails. Next I try to create an `ObjectInputStream` object using the following line: `ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)`.

This throws an `IOException` EVERY time!! What am I doing wrong?

I've tried using `fis` as a `FileInputStream` and as an `InputStream` object.
I'm able to write to a file using `ObjectOutputStream`.

Comment: be more specific about your exception. if permission denied then you've probably forgotten to set your storage permissions in the manifest file.

Comment: I don't see anything about a permissions issue, though because I'm not ruling that out which permissions should I use to read/write to internal storage? Not an SQLite Db, but a file.

Comment: try:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994291/ioexception-in-objectinputstream-in-java