# IOException in ObjectInputStream in java

Tags: java, io, deserialization, ioexception

I have problem with my code. I get IOException when I use readObject in my code. the whole program work correctly but when I want to use readObject I get this exception,
this is the code I use for saving object:

```
        File f = new File("employees.obj");
    ObjectOutputStream objOut = null;

    try {

        objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(f)));
        objOut.writeObject(newEmployee);
        objOut.flush();

        System.out.println("Object is serialized.");

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found!");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed!");

    } finally {

        if (objOut != null) {
            try {

                objOut.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

and it is the code I use for restoring object:

```
    File f = new File("employees.obj");
    ObjectInputStream objIn = null;
    ArrayList<Employee> c = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    try {
        objIn = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(f)));
        while (objIn.readObject() != null) {
            Person employee = (Person) objIn.readObject();
            System.out.println("hello");
            System.out.println(employee.toString());
        }
        System.out.println(c.toString());
        return c;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("1");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("3");
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        System.out.println("4");
    } finally {

        if (objIn != null) {
            try {
                objIn.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("4");
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
```

and the result in console:

```
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2553)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1296)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
at org.bihe.DeSerializer.deSerializeEmployees(DeSerializer.java:20)
at org.bihe.Main.enterAsManager(Main.java:238)
at org.bihe.Main.menu(Main.java:92)
at org.bihe.Main.main(Main.java:50)
```

Comment: Replace your `System.out.println("2");` with an `e.printStackTrace();` and include the stack trace in your question.

Comment: Also post your Person implementation.

Comment: Person implements Serializable,
I test this code with the 
Employee test = (Employee) objIn.readObject();
and something else, all classes impliments Serializable and manager extends employee extends person

Comment: java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2553)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1296)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
 at org.bihe.DeSerializer.deSerializeEmployees(DeSerializer.java:20)
 at org.bihe.Main.enterAsManager(Main.java:238)
 at org.bihe.Main.menu(Main.java:92)
 at org.bihe.Main.main(Main.java:50)

Comment: Please put the stack trace in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    while (objIn.readObject() != null) {
```

will deseralize one object (Person). Then the next line:

```
        Person employee = (Person) objIn.readObject();
```

attempts to deseralize the next object. If you're at the end of the file (EOF), then it throws 
`IOException`.

To fix this do something like this:

```
    Person employee;
    while ((employee = (Person)objIn.readObject()) != null) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println(employee.toString());
    }
```

The while compares `readObject()` with null and assigns it to `employee`.

Comment: I do that but now I get a nullPointerException!

Comment: in what line do u have nullPointerException?

Comment: in this line: System.out.println(employee.toString());

Answer (score 0):

You already read the object in the while loop test.

```
    while (objIn.readObject() != null) {
        Person employee = (Person) objIn.readObject();
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println(employee.toString());
    }
```

Change it to:

```
    for (Person employee = (Person) objIn.readObject(); employee != null; Person employee = (Person) objIn.readObject()) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        System.out.println(employee.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Nice `for` loop usage. It limits the scope of `employee`

Comment: I get the NULLPointerException!

Comment: in this line: System.out.println(employee.toString());

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the underlying problem of reading twice, you have another problem. EOFException just means you've reached the end of the stream. Catch it, and break out of the loop. At present your code incorrectly assumes that readObject() returns null at end of stream. It doesn't. It returns null if you wrote a null, which can happen any time, or never, depending entirely in what you wrote to the stream.

Comment: Unreachable catch block for EOFException. It is already handled by the catch block for IOException!!!!